# Why is the first letter of my tkinter window's title always lowercase?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The following code should create a window with the title, "HELLO WORLD".

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk(className='HELLO WORLD')
window.mainloop()
```

However, after I run it, the title ends up being "hELLO WORLD". No matter what I do, I can't prevent the first character from being lowercase.

I managed to fix the problem by putting a [Zero-width non-joiner](https://unicode-table.com/en/200C/) in front of the title, but why does this happen in the first place?

Comment: `className` is not the window title, try `window = tl.Tk(); window.title("HELLO WORLD")`

Answer (score 3):

Like ddejohn mentioned it. The **title** methode is used to change the title.

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("HELLO WORLD")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer was helpful, it doesn't answer _why_ the first character of a className is lowercase.